# Trigonometric inequality $\sin(2\pi \cos x)>0$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Solve the inequality $\sin(2\pi \cos x)>0$

My attempt:

$t:=2\pi \cos x$

$\sin t>0$

$2k\pi<t<\pi+2k\pi, k\in \Bbb Z$

$2k\pi<2\pi \cos x< \pi +2k\pi$

$k<\cos x<1/2+k\\$

$1)$ $\cos x>k$ and $2)$ $\cos x<1/2 + k$, $k \in\Bbb Z$

How do I write down the final solution?

Comment: The inequality is false in general. For example both lhs and rhs are zero at $x = 0, \pi/2$

Comment: @NilotpalSinha Sure, the OP wants to find which $ x $ this works for

Comment: @NilotpalSinha "solve the inequality"

Answer (score 2):

We have $k$ as integer  as $-1\le\cos x\le1$ for real $x$

For $k=-2, -2<\cos x<1/2-2$  which is impossible

For $k=-1, -1<\cos x<1/2-1$  (which is acceptable)

For $k=0, 0<\cos x<1/2$  (which is acceptable)

For $k=1, 1<\cos x<1/2+1$  which is impossible

Answer (score 1):

You're very close! $ \cos $ is always between $ -1 $ and $ 1 $. Therefore, either $ k = -1 $ or $ k = 0 $. You should be good from there.